# How do we show the full post on the Moderator Flags page (like the Suggested Edits page)?

Tags: support, user-interface, moderator-tools, flags

The past few days I've noticed I have a button to review moderator flags on the stackoverflow  toolbar, and I'm assuming it's because there's over 200-300 flags and my rep is fairly high.

I looked through a few but quickly got tired of this because I usually have to go into the question itself to review the question, and switching pages takes time and destroys my attention span.

Would it be possible to make page to review moderator flags the same as the page that reviews edits, where it actually shows the full content of the question/answer the flag is about?

That way I could just scroll through questions and help out with ones I think I understand, instead of having to browse to each question in a new tab and waste time on ones that I don't know about and would prefer to leave for someone else. It would make me more willing to help out with moderator flags when they get backed up, and make the flag review process faster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an arrow in the upper left corner of each post on the flags page that you can click to expand the post and see its full contents.

[image: Flagged Post Expansion]

This works much faster than waiting for an entire page load.

Comment: =O I had no idea idea you could do that, thank you!

Comment: @Rachel No problem.  That arrow is tiny and easy to overlook.  :)